# Delete cache by key is not working Springboot Redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis

I would like to use Cache in my app.
I set up Redis, connection is OK, cache seems to work but i'm having some trouble..
First of all, can i use caching system like that with pagination ?

And my other problem is that when i use the deleteCheckConfigDeploiement method, it delete the content, but when i call getAllCheckConfigDeploiement it don't have delete the data from the cache..

```
@RestController
@Tag(name = "EndPoint CC : ", description = "Check Configuration")
@CrossOrigin()
@RequestMapping("/api/v3")
public class CheckConfigEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private ICheckConfigService iCheckConfigService;

    @Operation(summary = "Récupération de tous les checkconfigs")
    @GetMapping("/check-config-deploiement")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @Cacheable(value = "check-config-deploiement")
    public PagedResponse<CheckConfigDeploiementDTO> getAllCheckConfigDeploiement(
            @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER) @Size(min = 0) Integer page,
            @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false, defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) @Size(min = 1) Integer size,
            @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = false, defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_SORT_BY) String sortBy) {
        return iCheckConfigService.getAllCheckConfigDeploiement(page, size,
                sortBy);

    }

    @Operation(summary = "Récupération des checkconfigs en fonction du namespace")
    @GetMapping("/check-config-deploiement/namespace/{namespace}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @Cacheable(value = "check-config-deploiement", key = "#namespace")
    public PagedResponse<CheckConfigDeploiementDTO> getAllCheckConfigDeploiement(
            @PathVariable String namespace,
            @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER) @Size(min = 0) Integer page,
            @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false, defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) @Size(min = 1) Integer size,
            @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = false, defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_SORT_BY) String sortBy) {
        return iCheckConfigService.getCheckConfigDeploiementByNamespace(
                namespace, page, size,
                sortBy);
    }

    @Operation(summary = "Récupération des checkconfigs en fonction des paramètres")
    @GetMapping("/check-config-deploiement/namespace/{namespace}/composant/{composant}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @Cacheable(value = "check-config-deploiement",key="#namespace, #composant")
    public PagedResponse<CheckConfigDeploiementDTO> getAllCheckConfigDeploiement(
            @PathVariable String namespace, @PathVariable String composant,
            @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER) @Size(min = 0) Integer page,
            @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false, defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) @Size(min = 1) Integer size,
            @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = false, defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_SORT_BY) String sortBy) {
        return iCheckConfigService
                .getCheckConfigDeploiementByNamespaceAndComposant(
                        namespace, composant, page, size,
                        sortBy);
    }

    @Operation(summary = "Récupération des checkconfigs en fonction des paramètres")
    @GetMapping("/check-config-deploiement/namespace/{namespace}/date/{dateDebut}/{dateFin}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @Cacheable(value = "check-config-deploiement", key = "#namespace, #dateDebut, #dateFin")
    public PagedResponse<CheckConfigDeploiementDTO> getAllCheckConfigDeploiement(
            @PathVariable String namespace,
            @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date dateDebut,
            @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) Date dateFin,
            @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false, defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_PAGE_NUMBER) @Size(min = 0) Integer page,
            @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false, defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE) @Size(min = 1) Integer size,
            @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = false, defaultValue = AppConstants.DEFAULT_SORT_BY) String sortBy) {

        return iCheckConfigService
                .getCheckConfigDeploiementByNamespaceAndLogCreatedAtBetween(
                        namespace, dateDebut,
                        dateFin, page, size,
                        sortBy);
    }

    @Operation(summary = "Suppression d'un CheckConfig")
    @DeleteMapping("/check-config-deploiement/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    @CacheEvict(value = "check-config-deploiement", key = "#id")
    public void deleteCheckConfigDeploiement(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        iCheckConfigService.deleteCheckConfigDeploiement(id);
    }

    @Operation(summary = "Insertion d'un CheckConfig")
    @PostMapping("/check-config-deploiement")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @CacheEvict(value = "check-config-deploiement", allEntries = true)
    public CheckConfigDeploiement saveCheckConfigDeploiement(
            @Valid @RequestBody CheckConfigDeploiementDTO checkConfigDeploiementDTO) {
        return iCheckConfigService.saveCheckConfig(checkConfigDeploiementDTO);
    }

    @Operation(summary = "Update d'un CheckConfig")
    @PutMapping("/check-config-deploiement/{id}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @CacheEvict(value = "check-config-deploiement", key = "#id")
    public CheckConfigDeploiement updateCheckConfigDeploiement(
            @PathVariable Integer id, @Valid @RequestBody CheckConfigDeploiementDTO checkConfigDeploiementDTO) {

        return iCheckConfigService.updateCheckConfigDeploiement(id, checkConfigDeploiementDTO);
    }

}
```

Comment: You put into the cache under `key = "#namespace, #dateDebut, #dateFin"`, but tried to evict a different `key = "#id"`.

Comment: So what can i do ? I can't put #id there.. i don't have it